# Kivy Android App - Switching screens with a swipe

Tags: android, python, kivy, screen, swipe

Every example I've found thus-far for development with Kivy in regards to switching screens is always done using a button, Although the user experience doesn't feel very "native" or "Smooth" for the kind of app I would like to develop.

I was hoping to incorperate swiping the screen to change the active screen.

I can sort of imagine how to do this by tracking the users on_touch_down() and on_touch_up() cords (spos) and if the difference is great enough, switch over to the next screen in a list of screens, although I can't envision how this could be implemented within the kv language

perhaps some examples could help me wrap my head around this better?

P.S.
I want to keep as much UI code within the kv language file as possible to prevent my project from producing a speghetti-code sort of feel to it. I'm also rather new to Kivy development altogether so I appologize if this question has an official answer somewhere and I just missed it.

Comment: Perhaps [gestures](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.gesture.html) can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a `Carousel` instead of `ScreenManager`, but if you want that logic while using the `ScreenManager`, you'll certainly have to write some python code to manage that in a subclass of it, then use it in kv as a normal ScreenManager. Using `previous` and `next` properties to get the right screen to switch to depending on the action. This kind of logic is better done in python, and that doesn't prevent using the widgets in kv after.